# How to make a POST with empty body using OKHttp

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I'm facing a different Api Service which I have to request using POST but with no body content, I'm sending a image converted to base64, I've been searching about that issue and I found this "solution", which it didn't work :

1 :

```
RequestBody reqbody = RequestBody.create(null, new byte[0]);  
Request.Builder formBody = new Request.Builder().url(url).method("POST",reqbody).header("Content-Length", "0");
```

2 :

```
request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(BASE_URL + route)
                .method("POST", RequestBody.create(null, new byte[0]))
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();
```

Even I explicit saying that is a POST method, it keeps send a GET request and not a POST request. Thanks!

My Activity :

```
public String SendImage(String image64) throws IOException{
    //RequestBody reqbody = RequestBody.create(null, new byte[0]);

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://ap.imagensbrasil.org/api/1/upload/?key=9c9dfe77cd3bdbaa7220c6bbaf7452e7&source=" + image64 + "&format=txt")
            .method("POST", RequestBody.create(null, new byte[0]))
            .header("Content-Length", "0")
            .build();

    OkHttpClient Client = client.newBuilder() .readTimeout(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
    Response response = Client.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working on retrofit , so if you continue with Retrofit v2.0 you can use this :

```
public class Base64EncodeRequestInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request originalRequest = chain.request();
        Request.Builder builder = originalRequest.newBuilder();

        if (originalRequest.method().equalsIgnoreCase(POST)) {
          builder = originalRequest.newBuilder()
              .method(originalRequest.method(), encode(originalRequest.body()));
        }


        return chain.proceed(builder.build());
    }

    private RequestBody encode(RequestBody body) {
        return new RequestBody() {
            @Override
            public MediaType contentType() {
                return body.contentType();
            }

            @Override
            public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
                Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
                body.writeTo(buffer);
                byte[] encoded = Base64.encode(buffer.readByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                sink.write(encoded);
                buffer.close();
                sink.close();
            }
        };
    }
}
```